# Busqueda con php y sql server

Tags: sql-server, busqueda

Tengo una página donde relleno un formulario de busqueda y envio mediante un POST los datos a otra pagina php. Los datos pueden ir con un valor o pueden estar vacios.

```
        $Etiq = $_POST["Etiq"];
   $RespImp = $_POST["RespImp"];
   $Fec_Inic = $_POST["Fec_Inic"];
   $Fec_Fin = $_POST["Fec_Fin"];
   $User_Cre = $_POST["User_Cre"];
   $User_Com = $_POST["User_Com"];
   $Orig = $_POST["Orig"];
   $P_R_O = $_POST["P_R_O"];
   $Prioridad = $_POST["Prioridad"];
   $Eficaz = $_POST["Eficaz"];
   $User_Resp = $_POST["User_Resp"];
   $Fec_PrevIni = $_POST["Fec_PrevIni"];
   $Fec_PrevFin = $_POST["Fec_PrevFin"];
   $Estado = $_POST["Estado"];
   $Process = $_POST["Process"];


$sentencia = $base_de_datos->query("select * , FechaAlt=convert(varchar(10), Fec_Alta, 103), FechaPrev=convert(varchar(10), Fec_Prev, 103), FechaImp=convert(varchar(10), Fec_Imp, 103) from IncidenciasAlbeniz  where  (Fec_Alta >= '$Fec_Inic'  and Fec_Alta <=  '$Fec_Fin') OR User_Cre = '$User_Cre'  OR User_Com = '$User_Com'  OR Orig = '$Orig' OR P_R_O = '$P_R_O'  OR Prioridad = '$Prioridad' OR Etiqueta1 = '$Etiq' OR ResponsableImp = '$RespImp'   OR Estado = '$Estado'   OR Eficaz = '$Eficaz'   OR User_Resp = '$User_Resp'  OR Process = '$Process'  OR (Fec_Prev >= '$Fec_PrevIni' and Fec_Prev <=  '$Fec_PrevFin')");
$IncidenciasAlbeniz = $sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
?>
```

Algo estoy haciendo mal en el where. Ya que cuando relleno el formulario y dejo algunos campos vacios y otros con datos, los resultados que me devuelve la consulta no son coincidentes. Por ejemplo si dejo todo vacio y en el formulario solo relleno $Estado = 'ABIERTA' la consulta me devuelve las ABIERTAS y el resto.

Comment: Hola Alejandro ¿En vez de poner una foto del código podrías añadir tu código escrito?

Comment: Claro, lo escribo en un nuevo comentario